# How can I make a thread in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I want to parse url after I input something in text dialog and comfirm.
But it will cost time, so I created a thread to do it:

```java
public void onAddMod(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        status.setText("Downloading...");
        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("fabric-api");
        dialog.setTitle("Add a mod from Modrinth");
        dialog.setHeaderText("");
        dialog.setContentText("Modrinth slug: ");
        Optional<String> opt = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            try {
                // parsing
                Information info = ModrinthUtils.information(opt.get());
                DataSaver.MODS.put(info.modName(), info);
                ModList.getItems().add(info.modName());
            } catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }
        status.setText("Finished!");
    });
}
```

*`onAddMod()` will run after the button pressed

However, `Platform.runLater()` CANNOT let the thread "run later". When I confirm, the program stopped until parsing finished.

How can I fix it? Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the documentation of [`Platform#runLater(Runnable)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)):

> Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future. This method, which may be called from any thread, will post the Runnable to an event queue and then return immediately to the caller. The Runnables are executed in the order they are posted.

But your `onAddMod` method is already being invoked by the *JavaFX Application Thread*. So, all your current code is doing is delaying the code's execution by a small amount.

You need to modify your code to use a background thread. Creating a new thread is done the same way as in any other Java application. If you want just a one-off thread, then create a new [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) instance, passing it a `Runnable`, and call `Thread#start()`. If you want a thread pool, then make use of the [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) / [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) API (also see the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class).

But as this is a JavaFX application, you probably also want to make use of the classes in the [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. See [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546). For example:

```java
public void onAddMod(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
  // run dialog code on FX thread
  TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("fabric-api");
  dialog.setTitle("Add a mod from Modrinth");
  dialog.setHeaderText("");
  dialog.setContentText("Modrinth slug: ");
  Optional<String> opt = dialog.showAndWait();

  if (opt.isPresent()) {
    Task<Information> task = new Task<>() {

      @Override
      protected Information call() throws Exception {
        // this method is invoked on the background thread

        updateMessage("Downloading..."); // update coalesced on FX thread
        Information info = ModrinthUtils.information(opt.get());
        updateMessage("Finished!"); // update coalesced on FX thread
        return info;
      }
    };

    // might want to unbind when the task finishes?
    status.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

    task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
      // this event handler is invoked on the FX thread

      Information info = task.getValue();
      DataSaver.MODS.put(info.modName(), info);
      ModList.getItems().add(info.modName());
    });

    // this event handler is also invoked on the FX thread
    task.setOnFailed(event -> /* notify user of failure */ );

    Thread thread = new Thread(task); // 'Task' is a 'Runnable'
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start(); // start the background thread
  }
}
```

The above makes use of [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and creates a one-off `Thread` instance. See [`Service`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) for a reusable JavaFX worker, which also makes use of `Executor` so that you reuse the same thread pool.

I didn't know if:

```java
DataSaver.MODS.put(info.modName(), info);
ModList.getItems().add(info.modName());
```

Needed to be executed on a certain thread, so I just put it on the FX thread, same as your current code, via the `onSucceeded` handler (the example puts the parsing on the background thread, if I understand your code correctly).